# How to change output of the array hash using the map or group_by in ruby?

Tags: ruby, api

I have this array of hash where i have to separate same value object and group it by country base on date.
I try to use group_by but i only manage to get the countries i cannot separate the reported_date
outside of array hash.
notice one of the object is thesame

```
"reported_date": "2020-04-01"
```

i want it to be outside of every hash so it only print once.

heres my hash

```
[
    {
        "reported_date": "2020-04-01",
        "country": "Italy",
        "confirmed": 110574,
        "deaths": 13155,
        "recovered": 16847
    },
    {
        "reported_date": "2020-04-01",
        "country": "Spain",
        "confirmed": 104118,
        "deaths": 9387,
        "recovered": 22647
    },
    {
        "reported_date": "2020-04-01",
        "country": "US",
        "confirmed": 83948,
        "deaths": 1941,
        "recovered": 0
    }
]
```

and i want to change something like this

```
{
    "reported_date": "2020-04-01",
    "countries": [
        {
            "country": "Italy",
            "confirmed": 110574,
            "deaths": 13155,
            "recovered": 16847
        },
        {
            "country": "Spain",
            "confirmed": 104118,
            "deaths": 9387,
            "recovered": 22647
        },
        {

            "country": "US",
            "confirmed": 83948,
            "deaths": 1941,
            "recovered": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```rb
[
    {
        "reported_date": "2020-04-01",
        "country": "Italy",
        "confirmed": 110574,
        "deaths": 13155,
        "recovered": 16847
    },
    {
        "reported_date": "2020-04-01",
        "country": "Spain",
        "confirmed": 104118,
        "deaths": 9387,
        "recovered": 22647
    },
    {
        "reported_date": "2020-04-01",
        "country": "US",
        "confirmed": 83948,
        "deaths": 1941,
        "recovered": 0
    }
].group_by { |h| h[:reported_date] }.map do |date, rest|
  {
    reported_date: date,
    countries: rest.map { |h| h.reject! { |k| k == :reported_date } }
  }
end
```

Returns

```rb
[
  {
    :reported_date => "2020-04-01",
    :countries => [
      {
        :country => "Italy",
        :confirmed => 110574,
        :deaths => 13155,
        :recovered => 16847
      },
      {
        :country => "Spain",
        :confirmed => 104118,
        :deaths => 9387,
        :recovered => 22647
      },
      {
        :country => "US",
        :confirmed => 83948,
        :deaths => 1941,
        :recovered => 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Theres an error `undefined method `except' for #<Hash:`

Comment: I mistakenly assumed you were using Rails. Updated the answer to not depend on Rails.

Comment: actually I am using rails thats the output. actually i modify a little bit your answer since your rejecting or except still output id and created_at. I use map then print the individual object that i  i need

Comment: If you need a whitelist of attributes, I suggest using `Hash#slice!`. In any case, if this helped you, consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your array were:

```
arr = [
  { date: "2020-04-01", country: "Italy", confirmed: 110574, deaths: 13155},
  { date: "2020-04-02", country: "Spain", confirmed: 104118, deaths:  9387},
  { date: "2020-04-01", country: "US",    confirmed:  83948, deaths:  1941},
  { date: "2020-04-02", country: "Italy", confirmed: 120431, deaths: 13394}
]
```

Depending on your needs you might find it more convenient to reorganize your data, possibly in one of the following two ways.

**#1**

```
keeper_keys = arr.first.keys - [:date, :country]
  #=> [:confirmed, :deaths] 
h = arr.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g[:date]] =
  (h[g[:date]] || {}).merge(g[:country]=>g.slice(*keeper_keys)) }
  #=> {"2020-04-01"=>{
  #       "Italy"=>{:confirmed=>110574, :deaths=>13155},
  #       "US"=>{:confirmed=>83948, :deaths=>1941}
  #     },
  #    "2020-04-02"=>{
  #       "Spain"=>{:confirmed=>104118, :deaths=>9387},
  #       "Italy"=>{:confirmed=>120431, :deaths=>13394}
  #     }
  #   }
```

`h[g[:date]] || {}` returns an empty hash if `h` has no key `g[:date]`.

This allows us to easily compute, for example:

*Deaths by date and country*

```
p = h.transform_values { |g| g.transform_values { |f| f[:deaths] } }    
  #=> {"2020-04-01"=>{"Italy"=>13155, "US"=>1941},
  #    "2020-04-02"=>{"Spain"=>9387, "Italy"=>13394}}
```

*Total deaths by date*

```
p.transform_values { |g| g.values.sum }
  #=> {"2020-04-01"=>15096, "2020-04-02"=>22781}
```

**#2**

```
keeper_keys = arr.first.keys - [:date, :country] 
  #=> [:confirmed, :deaths]
h = arr.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g[:country]] =
  (h[g[:country]] || {}).merge(g[:date]=>g.slice(*keeper_keys)) }
  #=> {"Italy"=>{
  #      "2020-04-01"=>{:confirmed=>110574, :deaths=>13155},
  #      "2020-04-02"=>{:confirmed=>120431, :deaths=>13394}
  #    },
  #    "Spain"=>{
  #      "2020-04-02"=>{:confirmed=>104118, :deaths=>9387}
  #    },
  #    "US"=>{
  #      "2020-04-01"=>{:confirmed=>83948, :deaths=>1941}
  #    }
  #  }
```

`h[g[:country]] || {}` returns an empty hash if `h` has no key `g[:country]`.

This allows us to easily compute:

*Deaths by country and date*

```
p = h.transform_values { |g| g.transform_values { |f| f[:deaths] } }    
  #=> {"Italy"=>{"2020-04-01"=>13155, "2020-04-02"=>13394},
  #    "Spain"=>{"2020-04-02"=>9387},
  #    "US"=>{"2020-04-01"=>1941}}
```

Notice that this expression is the same as the one used earlier to obtain deaths by date and country.

*Total deaths by date*

```
p.transform_values { |g| g.values.sum }
  #=> {"Italy"=>26549, "Spain"=>9387, "US"=>1941}
```

Again, this is the same expression as the one used earlier to compute total deaths by country.

Better yet, use a database!